# Is it possible to break out of a mysql stored procedure with something like return?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

In MySQL is there the equivalent of MS SQL's `RETURN` statement in Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for the [LEAVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/leave-statement.html) statement -- scroll down to users' comments for usage examples.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?q=leave
Link was dead. This is a little bit helpful (saves you one search)